# Print hosts in group with Ansible

Tags: ansible

I have the following:

```
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    list_of_groups:
      - group_1
      - group_2

  tasks:
    - name: debug
      debug:
        msg: "Host group {{ item }} has host {{ groups[item] }}"
      loop: "{{ list_of_groups }}"
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true
```

In my inventory file, group `group_1` has 3 hosts, and group `group_2` has 2 hosts. Currently the task above runs 2 times (one time for each group). And with each run it shows all hosts in that specific group. But I want that it runs for 5 times (because I have 5 hosts). And with each run it should only show 1 single host and not all hosts in the group.

Comment: Without any further information about your use case and what you try achieve it looks for me currently like you try to re-implement existing functionality from `ansible-inventory all --graph`,  `ansible-inventory group_1 --graph`,  `ansible-inventory group_2 --graph`, `ansible-inventory --toml --list`, etc.. See also [`ansible-inventory`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/cli/ansible-inventory.html).

Comment: @U880D: Instead of debug I want to use a different module, but for troubleshooting I used debug. I really want to use it in a playbook and not get the results using command line tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the inventory

```bash
shell> cat hosts
[group_1]
host_a
host_b
host_c

[group_2]
host_d
host_e
```

and the list of the groups

```yaml
  list_of_groups:
  - group_1
  - group_2
```

---

[*extract*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html#selecting-values-from-arrays-or-hashtables) and [*flatten*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html#managing-list-variables*) the lists

```yaml
  list_of_hosts: "{{ list_of_groups|map('extract', groups)|flatten }}"
```

gives you the list you want to iterate

```yaml
  list_of_hosts:
  - host_a
  - host_b
  - host_c
  - host_d
  - host_e
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    list_of_groups:
      - group_1
      - group_2
    list_of_hosts: "{{ list_of_groups|map('extract', groups)|flatten }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: list_of_hosts
      run_once: true

    - debug:
        msg: "I'm doing something for {{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ list_of_hosts }}"
      run_once: true
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook  pb.yml 

PLAY [all] ***********************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [host_a] => 
  list_of_hosts:
  - host_a
  - host_b
  - host_c
  - host_d
  - host_e

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [host_a] => (item=host_a) => 
  msg: I'm doing something for host_a
ok: [host_a] => (item=host_b) => 
  msg: I'm doing something for host_b
ok: [host_a] => (item=host_c) => 
  msg: I'm doing something for host_c
ok: [host_a] => (item=host_d) => 
  msg: I'm doing something for host_d
ok: [host_a] => (item=host_e) => 
  msg: I'm doing something for host_e

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
host_a: ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

Q: ***"It should also print the group."***

A: [*intersect*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html#selecting-from-sets-or-lists-set-theory) *list_of_groups* and [*group_names*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html#special-variables)

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "I'm doing something for {{ item }} which is a member of {{ my_groups }}"
      loop: "{{ list_of_hosts }}"
      vars:
        my_groups: "{{ hostvars[item].group_names|intersect(list_of_groups) }}"
      run_once: true
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  msg: I'm doing something for host_a which is a member of ['group_1']
  msg: I'm doing something for host_b which is a member of ['group_1']
  msg: I'm doing something for host_c which is a member of ['group_1']
  msg: I'm doing something for host_d which is a member of ['group_2']
  msg: I'm doing something for host_e which is a member of ['group_2']
```

Comment: I think I wasn't clear enough with my question, sorry for that. It should not only print the host, but it should also print the group: "I'm doing something for <host> which is a member of <group>"

Comment: A host can be a member of more groups. Do you want to print them all (except *all* and *ungrouped*)? See *group_names* in [Special Variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html#special-variables).

Comment: No, not all groups. Only the groups that are specified in "list_of_groups".

Comment: I added an example.

Answer (score 1):

Note that all of the above looks like an anti-pattern and an [X/Y problem](https://xyproblem.info). But to answer your direct question, in a nutshell:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  
  vars:
    list_of_groups:
      - group1
      - group2

  tasks:
    - name: Do something with host in given groups
      debug:
        msg: "I'm doing something for {{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ q('ansible.builtin.inventory_hostnames', list_of_groups | join(':')) }}"
```